# AS400 SQL Dynamic Delete issue

Tags: sql, dynamic, ibm-midrange, sql-delete, db2-400

Some background...
I have 20 + Files.
I read these file names from a prebuilt table building a subfile screen. 
I select 1 file then build another screen with the contents of file selected.
I then select the record I want to delete,   so far so good...

```
eval      MySQL  = stat3 + %trimr(scrwcrd) + STAT3B
```

my SQL Statement which reads in debug

```
MySQL =  DELETE FROM FILESEL WHERE K00001 = ? with NC 

PREPARE STAT3 from :MYSQL

EXECUTE STAT3 using :PROD
```

where :prod is the variable supplied from Screen selection

My sqlcod ends up at 100 with sqlstt = 2000 after the EXECUTE  indicating ROW not found for Delete.
Now for a fact this is not the case.    I see the record on the file selected and I see the value of PROD  using debug     any ideas...

Comment: One idea: Some punctuation, paragraph breaks, code highlighting, etc.. would make this maybe actually legible, and not a long blog of random sense-free verbiage.

Comment: Here goes then                                                      
eval      mysql3 = stat3 + %trimr(scrwcrd) + STAT3A   
          + STAT3B

Comment: @MarcB since DXP is a brand new user, it seems more helpful to either point them to the markdown instructions, or do the edit for them. Those who are familiar with the IBM-midrange environment (tagged as such) probably can read the code fine anyway.  For a first post, it's not too bad.

Comment: Check the statement that the system is actually running (which may include replaced parameters).  It's been too long - I can't remember if a high-enough job-log-level will spit this out for you.  If you have `*JOBCTL` authority, you can use iNav to start a job monitor, which does.

Answer (score 1):

What datatypes and length are the `K00001` field and `:PROD` host variable?

Equality could be an issue.  If they are character fields you may need to [`TRIM`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscatrimfun.htm)/[`%TRIM`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzasd/sc092508889.htm#bbtrim) the values in order to match.

Comment: k00001 & :prod both 7 numeric.    the delete statement when executed outside of the program works fine    it finds and deletes the required record.

Comment: Since the SQL statement contains a parameter marker, it **cannot run** "outside the program". But it indicates that the parameter marker is being replaced by a value that either doesn't match any value for `K00001` or doesn't match as an appropriate data type. We need to see the actual definitions for both `K00001' and `PROD` and possibly the debug value of `PROD` at the time the statement runs.